# Rails 4 wild card redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes, wildcard

I'm trying to find a way to redirect a route on Ruby on Rails 4 that should match the following:

```
http://domain.com/articles/GG-*
```

so every page containing a variety of numbers after `GG-` should be redirected. What I have so far:

```
get 'articles/GG-*', to: redirect("newdomain.com", status: 301), via :all
```

The redirect part will work if I just type one of the many `GG-12312313` pages on the route file itself, but I can't make a wildcard to catch all characters following `GG-`. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wildcards](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) for full segments of the route like `/foo/*bar`, but to match a more specific regexp, you need to use [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints).

```
get 'articles/:id',
  constraints: { id: /GG-.*/ },
  to: redirect("https://google.com", status: 301)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you